# Print data from a text file into a raw format?

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I get a text file and print the data into a raw format with all of the /n and /r and other code(s)?

Thanks
- Hyflex

Comment: maybe giantbloboftext.replace('\n','\\n') or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with open('filename.txt') as file:
    contents = file.read()
    print repr(contents)
```

Also you can open the file in an editor like notepad++ and click the paragraph button to see all linebreaks and other hidden characters.

Comment: Perfect, I found my problem thanks to this and it works perfectly now.

Answer (score 5):

```
print(repr(open(filename, 'rb').read()))
```

Comment: Perfect, I found my problem thanks to this and it works perfectly now.

I awarded the tick to the other guy because his answer came first, but both answers are good enough. Much appreciated.